# SQL MAX Subquery in arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management

Tags: arcpy, sql, error-000358

I am having an issue with subsequent subqueries in making a feature layer in arcpy.  My table has fields: OBJECTID, pointid (long), grid_code (double)

I can successfully extract MAX(grid_code), however it returns multiple values and as such I only need the row from selection where MIN(pointid) exists.

I have not been successful in using MakeFeatureLayer and then SelectByAttribute after that as arcpy effectively concatenates the two queries with AND, where I need to select using IN (I believe).

My code as currently stands below:

`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outpoint, "centroidpoint", "grid_code IN (SELECT MAX(grid_code) FROM point WHERE (SELECT MIN (pointid) FROM point))")`

outpoint is a point feature class in a geodatabase that is the result of a raster to point conversion.

Error is:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression grid_code IN (SELECT MAX(grid_code) FROM point WHERE (SELECT MAX (pointid) FROM point))
>   Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).

I believe error is in query, however I haven't found if I can do nested / subqueries of Max/Min funcitons.

Comment: "WHERE *numeric_constant*" isn't valid SQL -- maybe you meant `WHERE pointid = (subselect)`?  Please edit your question to specify the data source, since the capabilities of the data provider impact the SQL syntax.

Comment: What kind of geodatabase?  File geodatabase is different from enterprise, which all vary in flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 7):

An sql where clause can't incorporate sql functionality such as `MAX` or `MIN` because your input can only be what proceeds `WHERE` in an sql. Note how in the `Select By Attribute` window the first part of the SQL query is already provided:

[image]

The make feature layer sql where clause behaves in the same fashion. If you want to create a feature layer with a minimum or maximum value, you must first determine what that value is with prior python code. I like the [data access search cursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) for this because it does allow for a more robust sql clause.

Finding the maximum oid in a feature class and creating an SQL where clause with it:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("BlowOffFc", "OID@",
                            sql_clause =
                            (None,
                             "ORDER BY OBJECTID DESC")) as cursor:
    for maxOid, in cursor:
        break
del cursor
sql = "OBJECTID = {}".format (maxOid)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("BlowOffFc", "BlowOffFc_Max", sql)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, File Geodatabases (limited) and enterprise geodatabases (full) are the only types of geodatabases that support subqueries like you are doing. See here for examples: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm

You might begin with a more simple query and build up from there. Or try it in the Select by Attributes layer to see if it works before plugging it into the code.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outpoint, "centroidpoint", "grid_code IN (SELECT MAX(grid_code) FROM point WHERE (SELECT MIN (pointid) FROM point))")
```

The two main problems with this statement that I can see is the FROM is looking for a point layer or feature class and you are using something called outpoint to create the layer (two different layers). You might need to create a feature layer for point to load it into memory, or make sure the env.workspace is set properly. Other than that, this portion should work in theory:

```
"grid_code IN (SELECT MAX(grid_code) FROM point"
```

I tested something similar on my version of 10.2 using a layer for the second feature class.

This section also needs work:

```
WHERE (SELECT MIN (pointid) FROM point))
```

A where statement would also need an = or > or < or like. Perhaps it should be:

```
WHERE pointid = (SELECT MIN (pointid) FROM point))
```

I would start with just getting the first part working then add in the second where statement.

Edit:

Also if you are getting multiple gridcodes back you could add the DISTINCT keyword in front.

grid_code IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(grid_code) FROM point)